# mysqli code returns int instead of a string

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL database and echo the output using `json_encode`.

```
$fetch_from_table = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_from_table)) {
    $company['id'] = $row['id'];
    $company['name'] = $row['name'];
}

var_dump($company)
```

The above returns the output:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8"
           ["name"]=> string(12) "company name" }
```

Inside the database, the `id` is an int, not a string.  Nevertheless, the output is a string.  Consequently, `json_encode` formats it as a string too which is not what I want.

How do I change id from a string to an int?

Comment: PHP doesn't know that it's an integer, so tell it that it's an integer: `(int)$row['id'];` - this is called typecasting.

Comment: didn't change anything @Qirel

Comment: Have a look at the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option for [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: For @Qirel's suggestion to work you'd need to assign as well, i.e. `$row['id'] = (int)$row['id'];`

Comment: In MySQLi use [`bind_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php): it sets the correct type and handles `NULL`. Or try `$company['id']= (int)$company['id'];`

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405997/php-json-encode-output-number-as-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405997/php-json-encode-output-number-as-string)

Comment: @JonStirling `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` worked perfectly. Put as answer with php answer and I'll mark correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option for [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) which will automatically convert numeric items it understands to their non-string form in the encoded string.

A small caveat, do note though that if something you expect to be a string contains only numbers for example, this will still be converted.